# Grails test-app fails on CI server, but not on developer machine

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, maven

I have two machines, one Continuus integration server and one developer machine.

Both machines run the same version of java, maven, and grails and both are running Ubuntu.
The only difference that i can think of is that the CI is in a virtualized environment.

Some proof:

**CI java -version**

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

**DEV java -version**

```
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

**CI mvn -version**

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-1)
Java version: 1.6.0_24
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.32-31-server" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

**DEV mvn -version**

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-1)
Java version: 1.6.0_24
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "2.6.32-31-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

**CI grails**

```
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /usr/local/lib/grails-1.3.7
```

**DEV grails**

```
Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /home/netbrain/dev/apps/grails-1.3.7
```

I did a clean checkout from version control on both machines and deleted the folders `~/.m2` and `~/.ivy2` in order to avoid any indescrepencies.

When i run `grails test-app` on my CI server 6 tests seem to fail. When they on my DEV system all passes in the same case.

**CI grails test-app**

```
Tests Completed in 28213ms ...
-------------------------------------------------------
Tests passed: 14
Tests failed: 6
-------------------------------------------------------
```

**DEV grails test-app**

```
Tests Completed in 25889ms ...
-------------------------------------------------------
Tests passed: 20
Tests failed: 0
-------------------------------------------------------
```

When i look at the error messages im getting from the test output i can see things like:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<1> but was:<0>
not-null property references a null or transient value
```

As far as i can see, the tests are logically correct, and they shouldn' get these errors, especially when several tests that get the "transient value" error doesn't store anything to the database!

For me it seems like the problem lies somewhere in the combination of hibernate/memory-database/test phase.

There HAS to be some difference between the environments that is causing this issue. Does anyone have any tips on how i can proceed in order to debug the problem further?

Thanks again!

**EDIT**

Ok, so here is what i tried:

1. delete the folders `~/.m2`, `~/.ivy2`, `~/.grails`
2. run grails clean
3. run grails test-app

But still im seeing failed tests on my CI environment, but not on dev machine.

**EDIT**

Some new developments..

I tried running only the tests that failed on the CI, and it seems that when running `grails test-app :integration path.to.failing.tests` they all **PASS**! while running grails test-app causes those tests to **FAIL!** :(

Im totally baffled and clueless of whats going on here...

Comment: Have you tried removing the local Maven repository? Also check the Maven settings.xml, there might be a different configuration there.

Comment: Added this as a bug report to Grails project: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7513

Comment: And here is a followup question which may or may not be the cause of my issues. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080568/grails-mocked-data-from-a-unit-test-is-available-in-an-integration-test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would almost guarantee that this is a test pollution issue and the different servers are running the tests in different order.

The biggest clue of test pollution is always when you can run the test successfully by itself, but when you run other tests first, it fails.

I've had this happen multiple times where I've messed with the metaClass of a Class or an injected spring singleton (like a service bean) in one test, forgot to clean it up, and had other tests impacted by it.  Watch the output of which tests are getting run and compare them to make sure they're running in exactly the same order on both boxes.  If they aren't it's a test ordering issue.

The "easiest" way to find out what tests are interacting badly is to run `grails test-app` and pass in each test name in the same order that they are happening on the failing box (I normally use a text editor to slice out the test names from a previous run and concat them together so I know I have them in the same order).

Another potential issue is if one machine is using mysql and you've misconfigured to have "myisam" as the default storage engine rather than "innodb" (or another engine that supports transactions).  You can type "show engines;" on the mysql instance to see what engine is default.  Sounds like you're using hsqldb or another in memory db for your tests though, so this might not be your problem.

Comment: Very usefull post! ill look into it!. And yes im using in memory db for tests.

Comment: It seems you are quite right. Testing in the same order as the dev machine worked like a charm. Now i just have to compare the two run orders and try and find the culprit.

Comment: This always ends up as a binary search for me where I run the first half of the tests before the failing test, if there's no failure, then run the 2nd half of the tests.  Keep slicing the tests in half till you find out which other test class is causing the issue when run in isolation with the failing test.  Then when you identify the culprit, try commenting out half of the tests in that class till you find the bad test method (sometimes it's in setup).  Rinse, repeat till you identify what pollution you're leaving behind.

Comment: Thank you for leading me on to test pollution, this in turn helped me to figure out that i was actually seeing a bug in the grails test framework. this bug was causing test data leakage and in turn causing my tests to fail if run in a specific order. More on this bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080568/grails-mocked-data-from-a-unit-test-is-available-in-an-integration-test