# Grails. mocked data from a unit test is available in an integration test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, integration-testing

Im having a failed integration test because of test pollution (tests pass or fail depending on which order they are run in).

What baffles me a bit however is that it seems that a unit test where i have mocked some data with `mockDomain(Media.class,[new Movie(...)])` is still present and available in other tests, even integration tests.

Is this the expected behaviour? why doesn't the test framework clean up after itself for each test?

**EDIT**

Really strange, the documentation states that:

> Integration tests differ from unit tests in that you have full access to the Grails environment within the test. Grails will use an in-memory HSQLDB database for integration tests and clear out all the data from the database in between each test.

However in my integration test i have the following code

```
    protected void setUp() {
      super.setUp()
      assertEquals("TEST POLLUTION!",0,Movie.count())
      ...
    }
```

Which gives me the output:

```
TEST POLLUTION! expected:<0> but was:<1>
```

Meaning that there is data present when there shouldn't be!

Looking at the data that is present int he Movie.list() i find that the data corresponds to data set in a previous test (unit test)

```
protected void setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    //mock the superclass and subclasses as instances
    mockDomain(Media.class,[
            new Movie(id:1,name:'testMovie')
    ])
    ...
}
```

Any idea's of why im experiencing these issues?

Comment: Created a simple test app with grails where i could recreate the issue im having in my app. So i reported it as a bug @ http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7514

Comment: I get the same test failure in your sample app on Grails 1.3.7 Java 1.6.0_25

Comment: New link to GRAILS-7514: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/5842

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible that the pollution is in the test database. Check the `DataSources.groovy` to see what is being used for the test environment. If you have it set to use a database where 
`dbCreate` is set to something other than `"create-drop"`, any previous contents of the database could also be showing up.

If this is the case, the pollution has come from an entirely difference source. Instead of coming from the unit tests, it has actually come from the database, but when switching to run the integration tests you get connected to a real database with all the data it contains.

We experienced this problem, in that our test enviroment was set to have `dbCreate` as `"update"`. Quite why this was set for integration tests puzzled me, so I switched to use `dbCreate` as `"create-drop"` and make sure that when running test suites we started with a clean database.

Comment: hm, will be interesting to change to create-drop in my test app and see if the unit tests still fail. why "update" is default value for test environment is strange though.. Ill see if i can find the time to test it.